# How do I remove List of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a thesis. My goal is to remove the list of tables from the document.

My code below lists out the document structure

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} %use "twoside for two-sided numbering

%added by me
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{gsuthesisETD,multicol,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,geometry}
%%%MY additions
\usepackage{caption}
%for bibliography
\usepackage[english,backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true
}


\geometry{letterpaper,left=1.3 true in, right=1.2 true in, top=1in, 
          headheight =12pt, headsep =20pt, footskip =1in}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%Toggles: "true" or "false" 
\figurespagetrue 
\symbolpagefalse  
\dedicationpagetrue
\acknowledgmentspagetrue
\copyrightpagetrue
\sectionnumberstrue

% Fill in These Fields 
\title{Design and Implementation of an Automatic Generator for Word Matching Interactives}
\author{Evan M. Gertis}
\degree{Master of Science}
\major{Computer Science}
\dept{Department of Computer Science}
\school{Georgia Southern University}
\thesistype{Thesis}
\graduatedate{May 2022}
\graduateyear{2022}
\keywords{Automatic Programming, Computer Science Education, Online learning, Programming Synthesis, Word Matching} 
\cochair=0  %choose 1 if you have a co-chair
\symbolfile{symbols} % symbols go in the file "symbols.tex"
%\captiontype=1 %not used at this time
\appendname{APPENDICES}  % or APPENDIX for just one
\tocheader{Appendices}
\mybibname{REFERENCES}
\def\deansname{Dean's name} % Do NOT use "Dr." here.
\committeechair{Daniel Liang} % No. Dr.
\committeecochair{Co-advisor} % No Dr. 
\memberC{Andrew Allen}
\memberB{Ryan Florin}  
\degreeA{B.S., University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, 2017}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MACROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rmk}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{dfn}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ass}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newcommand{\RR}{{\mathbb R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}
\newcommand{\NN}{{\mathbb N}}
\newcommand{\rank}{{\rm rank}}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}
% \usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \makeatletter
% \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%                       \if@mainmatter
%                          \refstepcounter{chapter}%
%                          \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
%                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
%                       \else
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
%                       \fi
%                     \chaptermark{#1}%
% %                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
% %                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
%                     \if@twocolumn
%                       \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
%                     \else
%                       \@makechapterhead{#2}%
%                       \@afterheading
%                     \fi}
\begin{document}

%  Version: \today  % Comment this out for final version

  \input{abstract}
  \titlep            
  \copyrightpage  %optional (comment out if not used)
  \approvalpage      
  \input{dedication}  %optional
  \input{acknowledgments} %optional
  \tableofcontents 
  \include{Chapter-1}
  \include{Chapter-2}
  \include{Chapter-3}
  \include{Chapter-4}
  \include{Chapter-5}
  \include{Chapter-6}
  \include{8-Bib}
  

  \include{appendix}
  
%\scriptsize

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliography{refs}

% \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}
% \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

The specific section that I need to remove is shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of an almost empty page with the heading "list of tables"]

Any help figuring out how to remove this section would be great.

Comment: Code is useless if we can't compile it ourselves. We need a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) example starting from `\documentclass{...}`, and without `\input` or `\include` commands to files we don't have. This is not default behavior in the standard document classes, and is probably a feature of the particular one you're using, or some other package you've added. It's impossible to guess with the little info provided.

Comment: We don't know which class you are using, we don't know what is before `\begin{document}` (preamble). The command `\listoftables` inserts a list of tables, but we don't know if it is in your preamble, we don't know if it is inside the class of your thesis, we don't if whoever created it used this command of something else. And we also don't have your included files, please create MWEs without them.

Comment: I added the minimal reproducible example.